# pycharm is not getting installed

Tags: software-installation, python, pycharm

I had installed pycharm earlier by downloading from [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=linux).

After that, I removed my ubuntu os for some other reason and reinstalled ubuntu.

When I now run `$./pycharm.sh` from the `bin` directory after extracting `tar` file, pycharm never gets installed i.e, I'll have to every time run `$./pycharm.sh` to start pycharm.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing PyCharm only involves extracting the archive at your desired location and running `bin/pycharm.sh` file. But there is an extra step you can do to easily locate the application from Menus and Dash.

Open PyCharm and from its Menu -> Tools, Click on **Create Desktop Entry..** item. It will ask if you want to have the menu for all users or only the current one. Select your desired option.

From now on, you can see PyCharm in Unity Dash and other application menu.